# jQuery dataTables - filtering rows based on values in hidden field in column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a bootstrap table with a column with the below structure. The table is actually binding from Database using AJAX

```
ROW1:<td>....</td><td>...</td><td><i class='fa fa-arrow'></i><input type='hidden' value='0'</td>
ROW2:<td>....</td><td>...</td><td><i class='fa fa-bar'></i><input type='hidden' value='1'</td>
ROW3:<td>....</td><td>...</td><td><i class='fa fa-user'></i><input type='hidden' value='2'</td>
.........
.........
```

Here the value of the hidden fields changes dynamically upon binding from database or when adding each rows. On the header of the same column there is textbox and if we specify a value 0 it will filter the table based on that hidden field value in that column. Same way if I enter 2 it will lists only the rows based on 2 as the hidden field value of that particular column cell...

I cant try hidden columns since there is already lots of hidden columns for the filtering purpose.. So Requesting a solution with this mode...

Comment: You forget to close the `<input>`'s - `<input type='hidden' value='2'` should be `<input type='hidden' value='2'>` :) But am a little bit confused. Do you ask for a [**jQuery dataTables**](http://datatables.net/) solution to filter on the values of the hidden inputs?

Comment: @davidkonrad Sorry for that.. :) Yea.. I mean JQUERY Datatable filteration.. I doenst mean normal JQUERY filteration of the rows based on the value. I was trying to filter out the rows in the table as the DATATABLE filter or search system in Jquery datatable. The function should be the same as a the search text box in Datatable, but the search should occur in hidden field in one column only. Hope its clear now.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Not completely sure I understand what you want, but here goes. To take it from the top :

> *On the header of the same column there is textbox ...*

Like this?

```
<tr>
   <th>col #1</th>
   <th>col #2</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="search"/></th>
</tr>
```

> *... and if we specify a value 0 it will filter the table based on that hidden field value in that column.*

First, redefine the built in `html` type filter, so it returns the value of the hidden input box :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html'] = function ( sData ) {
    return $(sData).val();
}
```

Then assign a dataTables search to the input box in the header :

```
$("#search").on('keyup', function() {
    table.columns(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xdhgn55q/**

Comment: Excellent answer.. THis is exactly what I want.. But there is a little challenge which is if we redefine the default HTML type filter, will that affect other filters.. Honestly I missed to mention there is some other filters too which are normal html filters... But thats not a big deal.. I will try to compromise that part.. But this answer will clear the issue.. Thanks boss!

Comment: @sforsandeep - Great it is working! :) I will gladly update the answer tomorrow. Basically you just define a new type, like "hidden" or something else, like `$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['hidden'] = function (sData) { ...` and then set the columns' `sType` to be that type, eg "hidden". Then it will not conflict with existing html columns. At least I _believe_ that would be the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Found this message a year late, but still, why is it important to redefine the built in html type filter?

I managed to get a similar solution with only adding the http tabular elements.